# Database doesn't copy from asset although code seems fine

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have faced a weird situation. I used this code in most of my projects and worked fine, but I used it in a new project and it doesn't work I mean my database doesn't copy in user's phone. I reviewed each line and added log to each method but I don't receive any log. app works fine except for database part.

DBAdapter:

```
public class DBAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String DB_PATH;
private static String DB_NAME = "dictionary.db";
SQLiteDatabase db;
private Context c;



DBAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    c = context;
    try {
        createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (dbExist) {
        Toast.makeText(c,"done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Can't copy database" + e);
        }
    }

}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    DB_PATH = c.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    return dbFile.exists();
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    DB_PATH = c.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
    InputStream inputStream = c.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer))>0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer,0, length);
    }
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();
}

public void openDataBase() {
    DB_PATH = c.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (db != null)
        db.close();
    super.close();
}
}
```

Comment: then I think it's phone's issue. In which phone are you checking?

Comment: check on physical device and virtual . any problem with code?